# Template class inheritance linker errors

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, linker-errors

Suppose I have a class template `A`, and non-template class `B` inheriting from `A`. While `A` compiles OK, compiling `B` triggers linker errors. Specifically,

### A.hpp

```
#ifndef A_HPP_INCLUDED
#define A_HPP_INCLUDED

template <typename T>
class A { 
public:
    A();
    A(A<T>&& );
    virtual ~A();

    /* ... */
protected:
    T x;
};
#include A.tpp
#endif
```

### A.tpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

template <typename T>
A<T>::A() { ... }

template <typename T>
A<T>::A(A<T>&& other)
   : x(std::move(other.x)) { }

template <typename T>
A<T>::~A() { ... }
```

### testA.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

int main() {

    A<std::string> a;

    /* ... */

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling `testA.cpp` as follows is successful:

`$ g++ -std=c++11 testA.cpp`    <- OK

Next up is non-template `class B` inheriting from `A`:

### B.hpp

```
#ifndef B_HPP_INCLUDED
#define B_HPP_INCLUDED
#include "A.hpp"
class B
    : public A<std::string> {
public:
    B();
    virtual ~B();

    static A<std::string> foo();
};
#endif
```

### B.cpp

```
#include "B.hpp"

B::B()
    : A(std::move(foo())) { }

B::~B() { }

A<std::string> B::foo() { ... }
```

### testB.cpp

```
#include "B.hpp"

int main() {
    B b;

    /* ... */

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation of `testB.cpp` seems to go ok, but the linker is not a happy camper:

### Attempt 1

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 testB.cpp   
Undefined references to B(), and ~B()
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### Attempt 2

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 testB.cpp B.cpp
Undefined reference to B.foo()
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help/ideas are greatly appreciated. Mr. `ld` kept me up most of the night, and is threatening my sanity.

## Edit

Thank you Mike Seymour! This minimal example was not a true rendition of the real code, as indeed a qualifier was missing in the implementation, and was the wrench in the gear.

Comment: besides dots (no pun intended), I see nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: the 2nd attempt shows `Undefined reference to B.foo()`, meaning you didn't implement the `foo` static function

Comment: The first attempt won't work, since it's not linking with the file that defines the member functions of `B`. The second works for me, once I fix all the compile errors in the posted code. Perhaps you could post example code that does compile, and does reproduce the error.

Comment: Also, is that the exact error message? If I remove the definition of `foo`, then my version of GCC says "undefined reference to `B::foo()'"

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is not the actual error message - I translated from the actual errors for the sake of a minimal example (after the all nighter :) ). Gonna try bobah's suggestion, before posting the actual code and risking confusing everyone as much as myself :)

Comment: @AlmostSurely: It would be nice if you published at least the line containing `foo`invocation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Presumably, the real function corresponding to `B::foo` is `ParsedData::parsedStream`, which is a template and so needs to be defined in a header.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Either you are a magician, or you had access to an information we did not have... Anyway, that does not make a very good SO entry.

Comment: @Ad N, Hmm, I removed the actual code, since it's part of my final semester project - not Mike's fault at all. 

The problem seems to have been the missing qualifier in the implementation of `B::foo()`, which was not accurately conveyed in the minimal example. i.e., in the "real" `B.cpp`, I had `foo()` in the signature, rather than `B::foo()`. I appreciate all your responses :)

Comment: I also neglected to mention in the OP, (credit severe sleep deprivation), that `B::foo()` is itself a template, and as per Mike's advice, ought to be in its own header to avoid future linker complaints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your real code, `ParsedData::parsedStream` is a template, and so should be defined in a header so that it's available in every translation unit that might need to instantiate it.

Also, you don't define it even in the `.cpp` file, since you left off the `ParsedData::` qualifier and instead declared a different template at namespace scope.

Comment: Thank you!! I spent hours debugging and that oversight was holding me back!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you compile and link in two distinct passes:

```
g++ -c -std=c++11 -o B.o B.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++11 -o TestB.o TestB.cpp
g++ -o test.exe B.o TestB.o
```

If what I suggest breaks it will at least be clear what is missing where and you will be able to debug individual object files with `nm`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $ g++ -std=c++11 testB.cpp   
  Undefined references to B(), and ~B()
```

This one is obviously wrong (I just say that because I do not see why you are making this attempt).
You compile only one translation unit, that uses symbols defined in another (B.cpp) that is not compiled.

I think you should publish the actual content behind the `...`in *testB.cpp* to help find the problem. It could be in your usage of `foo()`

By anticipation : since `foo`is a static member method of your class, your invocation in the test should look like :

```
B::foo();
```